# How can I retrieve real time data from a website into c# winform app?

Tags: c#, web

I am creating a c# program that should get:
1) The current users on the web site.
2) Some basic info about those users. (Web browser, location).

How can I retrieve that data from a web site via C#?
 (I thought that I could upload a php/aspx  file that will save that data to a txt file, and      c# will download that data and show it) - is there a more simple way of doing this? or rather  a better way?

Comment: Are you trying to hack some random site? Or does the site belongs to you and you have ability to create any pages you want there?

Comment: It belongs to me. I have the ability to create pages there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very open question there are many ways you can go about this.

Why not just add an analytics package to your site (there are many free ones out there) and then if you wanted you could write a C# program to hook into the analytics API and download the data.

Comment: Can analytics give me the real time statistics(Current users...)? or only in an interval of ___ ?

Comment: Just had a quick look in google and it looks there's quite a few analytics providers that will let you get at the data in real time.  http://getclicky.com/ for example.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can create a **WebService** that contains your methods in the website and add a reference for web service in your winforms application and then you can easily call methods from **webservice** and used it.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) for this. Also you can use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`