# How can I retrieve data from a website to my winforms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a form where I want to insert a data in text box and retrieve the rest of the data from the website where it has all the details of it.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

I checked this question but its not helping me

[How can I retrieve real time data from a website into c# winform app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773075/how-can-i-retrieve-real-time-data-from-a-website-into-c-sharp-winform-app).
,
I am new so I dont understand most of the part.

Comment: You can use `WebClient`

Comment: The question is too broad. If you are asking about possible solutions, you have a few options like using a [`WebBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-overview) control or using [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and then extract the information from response. Please try something and then ask a specific question about specific problem by sharing a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebBrowser from Toolbox or Selenium Drivers. I prefer Selenium, it allow me full web navigation, you can fill fields with it, can submit forms, can extract information from websites and everything about web automation.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you will some content to textbox and based on the content added you want to get data from website? If its correct then you need to write code in your WinForm application to hit web service/web API to retrieve the data. Here you can find code to hit the web service/web API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client